# connect to sub directory in nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx

I deployed two nginx server, one is a reverse proxy in front and the other is just a web application server.

I seems working but if I create sub directory on web application server, I cannot reach the file under the sub directory like the below.

aaa.com/test/index.php
if I typed it on address bar of the browser, it throws 404;

but "aaa.com/test/" only directory goes to the folder and open the index.php.
I cceated a new file test.html under ~/test/ directory, nope.. it doesn't work.
I cannot reach the specific uri. I think every traffic goes to index.php on web app server. how can I fix this? any feedback would be appreciated.

My configuration is quite simple as follows:

nginx.conf in proxy server:

```
server {
    index index.php index.html;
    client_max_body_size 5M;
    server_name aaa.com;
    #root /var/www/api;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.20.2.10:80;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }

    location ~ \.(php|html)$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

    listen 443;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert/keys.key;
}
```

nginx in application server:

```
server {
    index index.php index.html;
    client_max_body_size 5M;
    root /var/www/api;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.(php|html)$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 15;
    }

    listen 80;
}
```

Comment: Your proxy server isn't just a reverse proxy, it also intercepts any URI that ends with `.php` or `.html` and processes them locally using PHP.